# Passed onClick function not identified as a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, onclick, react-props

I am passing an onClick function as a prop in my react app from one component to another. It gives an error which shows as `Uncaught TypeError: handleOnClick is not a function` . Here is my function which i am passing through,

```
propList = ['a', 'b', 'c']

const handleOnClick = (propArr: any) => {
    console.log('propArr===>', propArr)
}

<ChildComponent handleOnClick ={handleOnClick } propList={propList}/>
```

Here is the component which takes those props,

```
export const ChildComponent = (propList: any, handleOnClick : any) => {

const handleSubmit = () => {
    handleOnClick ('pass this to parent!')
}
   return(
       <button onClick={handleSubmit}>Submit</button>
   )
}
```

Do i need to change something specifically to overcome this situation?

Comment: where is `submitFunction`

Comment: an edit was added for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is incorrect:

```
export const ChildComponent = (propList: any, handleOnClick : any) => {
    // ...
};
```

Components take props as a single parameter which is an object. So at a minimum that should be:

```
export const ChildComponent = ({ propList, handleOnClick } : any) => {
    // ...
};
```

That uses destructuring in the parameter list to pick the `propList` and `handleOnClick` properties from the first parameter's value.

But there's no point in using TypeScript if you're just going to use the `any` type. Better to properly define a typed props interface for the component, and use that. For instance:

```
type ChildComponentProps = {
    propList: AppropriateTypeHere[];
    handleOnClick(propArr: AnotherAppropriateTypeHere[]): void;
}
export const ChildComponent = ({ propList, handleOnClick } : ChildComponentProps) => {
    // ...
};
```